# Align Widget inside Stack occupies full screen

Tags: flutter

I am using align to position widgets inside my stack. When I am using align in any of my child inside the stack then the stack occupies full screen. Otherwise the stack is of the height of the child that is tallest. I am confused here. Isn't align used to align children inside the stack?

Here is my code:

```
   bottomNavigationBar: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        color: Colors.greenAccent,
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 45,
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: Container(
         width: 80,
         height: 80,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent, shape: BoxShape.circle),
          child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: (){}),
        ),
      )

    ],
  )
```

Now when I remove the Align widget from my second child the stack is as big as its children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No problem there. It should occupy all the screen.

Stack size defined by non-positioned children. If you use Align, Stack has no limit, it will expand.

If you want relation between widgets, you must use Positioned widget instead.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html

From docs:

> The stack sizes itself to contain all the non-positioned children, which are positioned according to alignment (which defaults to the top-left corner in left-to-right environments and the top-right corner in right-to-left environments).

Also,

> The positioned children are then placed relative to the stack according to their top, right, bottom, and left properties.

Yes it will confuse for a while, even experienced devs may confuse sometimes when working with Stack. It's one of the hardest widgets to grasp fully.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer it was really helpful. It cleared my doubt and I was able to fix the problem I was having in my particular scenario.

Answer (score 3):

You did not give the `Align` widget values for its `widthFactor` and `heightFactor` , and the behavior you mentioned is expected according to the [Align class documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html)  :

> This widget will be as big as possible if its dimensions are constrained and widthFactor and heightFactor are null.

To confirm this I assigned the value `1.0` to both `widthFactor` and `heightFactor`, and it returned to its expected size (the size of the bigger widget which is the `FloatingActionButton`) :

```
 Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        widthFactor: 1.0,
        heightFactor: 1.0,
        child: Container(
          width: 80,
          height: 80,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent, shape: BoxShape.circle),
          child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: (){}),
        ),
      )
```

Answer (score 2):

The stack will be as big as its non-positioned children. Align makes the stack as big as the screen in my code above. To restrict the stack to be as big as its content. I wrapped the stack inside a container and gave it a fixed height.

Now the stack has limit to its height. So when I use align in its children now. It is only as tall as the Container containing it.

In short just wrap the stack with a Container with a fixed height.